# How to combine iptables rulesets

Tags: iptables, firewall, iptables-persistent

Say there are several `iptables` scripts (run at boot time), all of which run something like `iptables -A ...` to add rules. I'm thinking this could be improved, turning all those shell scripts into text files generated by `iptables-save`.

But I must be doing something wrong, trying to read all those rulesets. The script run at boot time would loop through those files and read them using `iptables-restore`. Of course with `-n` or `--noflush`. This works for some rules (stored in the default chains) but not for most of my rules which are in other chains. Below is an example of 2 rulesets that flush each other (reading set a, check; reading set b, check but set a is gone).

**How would you read a bunch of iptables rulesets?**

Example:

```
$ cat fake1-a.rules 
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [7:997]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:997]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:1810]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [28:1810]
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [344:84621]
:INPUT ACCEPT [344:84621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [296:37971]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [296:37971]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [102:26513]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [89:10767]
:TESTCHAIN - [0:0]
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -j DROP
COMMIT
$ cat fake1-b.rules 
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [7:997]
:INPUT ACCEPT [7:997]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:1810]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [28:1810]
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [344:84621]
:INPUT ACCEPT [344:84621]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [296:37971]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [296:37971]
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [102:26513]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [89:10767]
:TESTCHAIN - [0:0]
-A TESTCHAIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 54321 -j DROP
COMMIT
# cat fake1-a.rules | iptables-restore --noflush
# iptables -nL | grep DROP
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:12345
# cat fake1-b.rules | iptables-restore --noflush
# iptables -nL | grep DROP
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:54321
```

Comment: I would do it in a single file ... in fact that is what I am doing, but of course your use case is different. Does this yield any different outcome if you chain the files and leave out the `COMMIT` from them and then add the commit to the end yourself? E.g. in a subshell `(cat file1 file2 file2; echo "COMMIT")|iptables-restore -n` ... also not sure you need to declare the chain creation stanzas once again, perhaps the CHAIN gets re-created?

Comment: @0xC0000022L `iptables-restore: line 43 failed` (that's the last `COMMIT`). Without the echo, only the last ruleset is applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--noflush` option for `iptables-restore` doesn't work for user-defined chains, such as `TESTCHAIN`, only builtin chains.  Your best bet is to consolidate all of the `TESTCHAIN` rules into a single file and import that ruleset using `iptables-restore`.  You could find all the rules with something along the lines of:

```
egrep -r  "\sTESTCHAIN\s" firewall_rules_directory/*
```

Comment: Oh, interesting fact. Thanks. This is not even mentioned in the `man` page.

Comment: @0xC0000022L yea, it's funny what they don't tell you

Comment: So --noflush is basically broken, thanks for the confirmation. The regex would have to be more complex though, because it makes a difference what table the rules live in.

Comment: Just as an update to this, I'm using iptables v1.4.21 and the "iptables-restore -n" functionality now works correctly, including user-defined chains.